# Tracking DownloadProgress with synchronous download

Tags: c#, .net

basically i would like to do something like this:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            progress = (float) args.BytesReceived / (float) args.TotalBytesToReceive;
        };
    wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(noLastSegment + file), path);
}
```

this doesnt work, because the progress is only fired for asynchronous downloads like DownloadFileAsync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you've got some other thread like a UI thread if you can show progress, however maybe you've got a console app or something. You can easily use some kind of wait handle and set it when the download completes.

```
using (var completedEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim(false))
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, args) => 
    {
        completedEvent.Set();
    };
    wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        progress = (float) args.BytesReceived / (float) args.TotalBytesToReceive;
    };
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(noLastSegment + file), path);
    completedEvent.Wait();
}
```